# Find player's latest match whether player was the winner or loser

Tags: mysql

I have a table of match results with the following fields (and many more):

```
id
date_played
begin_time
end_time
winner_id   <-----foreign key into user.id
win_start_hcp
win_end_hcp
loser_id    <-----foreign key into user.id
loser_start_hcp
loser_end_hcp
```

I want to find the win_end_hcp for the last match played by user.id=X, whether he was a winner or a loser of that match.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this,

```
select top(1)  isWinner,  win_end_hcp
from
(
select 1 isWinner, end_time,  win_end_hcp from table1
where winner_id=X
union ALL
select 0 isWinner, end_time,  win_end_hcp from table1
where loser_id=X
)t4
order by t4.end_time desc
```

Comment: Maybe, but I don't understand what isWinner or t4 are. Also FYI, this is MySQL (I may not have been clear on that) so top(1) becomes limit 1 and it goes in a different part of the statement, but I get it.